# Unzip process works on one zip while it doesnt on another?

Tags: java, android, unzip

I've been trying to understand why my code doesnt work on a zip and it doesnt on another..
[THIS](https://www.box.net/shared/static/ot225gfdmebttm76i6fj.zip) zip unzips , and [THIS](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18331007/QuranReaders/hosari/1.zip) zip doesnt
Here is the code I use:

```
String zipFile = Path + FileName;


            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);

            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                UnzipCounter++;
                if (ze.isDirectory()) {
                    dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(Path
                            + ze.getName());
                    while ((Unziplength = zin.read(Unzipbuffer)) > 0) {
                        fout.write(Unzipbuffer, 0, Unziplength);                    
                    }
                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();

                }

            }
            zin.close();
```

Can anyone tell me why?

The zip doesnt work means that when it reaches the line "while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {".. ze is always null so it doesnt enter the loop so it doesnt extract anything.. I can open+unzip both files with WinRar..

Comment: Can you unzip your files using other tools (other than you Java program)?

Comment: This is exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561031/zipinputstream-getnextentry-is-null-when-extracting-zip-files

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual error:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:383)
    at gnu.java.util.zip.ZipFile$PartialInputStream.fillBuffer(ZipFile.java:647)
```

Looks like your zip file is corrupt.  WinRAR tends to ignore some kinds of corruption.

This is a personal gripe of mine - I believe it would be better if tools didn't do that sort of thing, because it means that whoever created the zip file probably doesn't know about the corruption either, and when you tell them, they will be all like, "but it isn't, look .. it opens in [insert broken app here]."